# Setting the profile picture from another field

Tags: plugins, avatar

I have a user registration a profile plugin where user has the ability to upload a top cover photo of their profile and hence it also has the cover photo option under the users tab in wp admin. What i what to be able to do is when the user set his/her cover photo it automatically sets it as the avatar as well.